# Redirect on form submit without JS

Tags: html, forms, redirect, gmail, ads

I have a HTML form with a URL as the action attribute. When the visitor submits the form, I need them to be redirected to a thank you page that is different than the action URL.

The base of my form looks like this

```
<form method="post" action="http://website.com/url-that-processes-form-info">
```

I've seen in other places, people were able to add a hidden field to trigger a redirect upon form submission, so I've tried adding this inside the form:

```
<input type="hidden" name="redirect" value="http://website.com/thank-you-page">
```

But this doesn't seem to work.

The problem is, I can't use any javascript (it's for a Gmail ad campaign, which strips away any JS), and I don't have access to the page that processes the form (which is in the forms action).

Is there any other way of doing this?

Comment: There are a number of ways to do this. Usually dependent on the form handler you're using. The other option would be to use AJAX to submit the form data and then redirect the browser to a thank you page afterward. Since you do not have access to the processing page, I would look at an AJAX option. It will require being able to run JS in the browser only, to send the data to the `action`.

Comment: I would have used AJAX, but this is for a Gmail display ad, which removes all javascript. It only accepts primitive html and inline CSS.

Comment: Then you will be forced to use the form handler, since HTML will only POST the data to the form action and display the resulting content from that form handler.

Comment: You're talking about a form for this: https://support.google.com/adwords/answer/7019461?co=ADWORDS.IsAWNCustomer%3Dfalse&hl=en

Comment: I may be reading something wrong, but it appears you can link to a thank you page in the setup of your ad campaign.

Comment: Yup that link is exactly what I was talking about. Thank you, you confirmed what I suspected. What I was looking to do can't be achieved within the limits of Gmail ads (Just HTML and inline css).

Comment: Look through this thread: https://www.en.advertisercommunity.com/t5/forums/v3_1/forumtopicpage/board-id/Manage-AdWords/page/2/thread-id/43936 I don't know if it applies to your issue, but they seem to show were you can add a link to a thank you page in the config under "Edit Links"

Comment: Thanks. I don't see the 'Edit Links' section there. There is a RedirectUrl which can be added to the teaser.txt file, but that is basically the URL used if someone clicks on the ad (not a redirect after form submit). Thanks a lot for looking into it thoroughly, it just doesn't work for my purposed though.